# how to use where condition in object oriented php inside function

Tags: php

i am my function is unable to use where condition in my function when i want to update appropriate user_id like this: `where user_id= ?`

**look at my function :**

```
public function createProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname,    $town) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where user_id= ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("ssss",$profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

**his the way i am calling createProfile function to let update**

```
      <?php

include './DbHandler.php';
$db = new DbHandler();


$response = array();

  if (  (   isset($_POST['profile_picture']) && isset($_POST['username']) &&     isset($_POST['businessname']) && isset($_POST['town'])  )!= '') {



 $profile_picture = $_POST['profile_picture'];
 $username = $_POST['username'];
 $businessname = $_POST['businessname'];
    $town = $_POST['town'];


   $res = $db->createProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname);

} 

?>
```

Comment: Well, that user_id would be a fifth parameter. You hand over only four. _Why_?

Comment: Please stop false tagging your questions, they have nothing to do with the CakePHP framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have five placeholders (`?`) = you should pass 5 parameters to `bind_param`. Easy way to do this is pass `$user_id` as an argument:

```
public function createProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town, $user_id) {  // user_id is a five parameter here
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where user_id= ?");
    // I suppose user_id has is `integer` type
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $user_id);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

As we don't know what is there in your class - maybe user id is somewhere in class properties (named `user_id` in my example), then you can use it like this:

```
public function createProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town) {  // NO user_id passed
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where user_id= ?");
    // I suppose user_id has is `integer` type
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $this->user_id);

    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Comment: i did it my not change to my table row

Comment: You did __what__? Did you check what user id you pass? Did you check errors?

Comment: This the way i am calling createProfile function  to let update profile_information table:    
$response = array();
 
if ( isset($_POST['profile_picture']) && isset($_POST['username']) && isset($_POST['businessname']) && isset($_POST['town']) && (isset($_POST['user_id'])  )!= '') {
 
   
     $profile_picture = $_POST['profile_picture'];
     $username = $_POST['username'];
     $businessname = $_POST['businessname'];
     $user_id = $_POST['user_id'];


  $response = $db->createProfile($profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $user_id);
 
}

Comment: no error what id did is this  but gives no change : public function createProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town, $user_id) {
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where user_id= ?");
    // I suppose user_id has is `integer` type
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $user_id);

    $stmt->execute();
}

Comment: Any errors? Do you really have user with such id? Do you really change any of user data?

Comment: No, this won't affect.

Comment: Please update your question with all your codes from comments.

Comment: i would like to ask  if user_id is somewhere else in other  function of my class if it can affect the function i create after

Comment: meanwhile after changing the function createProfile to  :                  `public function createProfile($profile_picture, $username,$businessname, $town) {  // NO user_id passed
    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("UPDATE profile_information set profile_picture = ?, username= ?, businessname= ?, town= ? where user_id= ?");
    
    $stmt->bind_param("ssssi",$profile_picture, $username, $businessname, $town, $this->user_id);

    $stmt->execute();
} `      **i get an error : Warning: Missing argument 4 for DbHandler::createProfile()**